# Java String Comparison

Tags: java, string, actionlistener

The following code is a part of my program

```
    String [] currency = { "Euro" , "USD" , "Pound" };
private JComboBox
C1 = new JComboBox(currency),
C2 = new JComboBox(currency);
String s,r;
double i,j =0,k=0;
```

................

```
private ActionListener d = new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
Object obj = C2.getSelectedItem();

r = "" + obj;
st.setText(r);
System.out.println(r);
System.out.println(currency[0]);

if (r == currency[0])
{

k=1;
}

if (r == currency[1])
{
k = 1.161;
}

if (r == currency[2])
{
k= 0.954;
}
System.out.println(k);
}
};
```

when r is printed the output is good same case for the printing of currency[0]. The problem is that k is always seen as 0.00. I think it has to do with the comparison of the strings.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you search for java string comparison first?

Comment: This comes up at least once a week...

Answer (score 4):

Use `equals` for string comparison E.g.,  `"string".equals("other string");` or in your case

```
r.equals(currency[0])
```

When using `==` on objects you are only comparing references (i.e., memory location, not actual content equality).

You might also be interested in using [`Enums`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) for your currency sample.

Answer (score 3):

compare the two strings by

```
r.equals(currency[0])
```

or

```
r.equalsIgnoreCase(currency[0])
```

when you don't care about the case of the characters (uppercase or lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `equals` for string comparison, and remember to put the string that is not `null` first:

```
"Hello".equals(myString)
```

or in your case:

```
r.equals(currency[0])
```